# Determining number of characters in SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm looking to parameterize a SQL script that holds more than 8000 characters, and since a variable can only hold 8000 characters, I am wondering if there is a way to determine how many characters are in a specific script, so I would have some foresight on when I should use a new variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are referring to SQL Server please select the specific tag. If you are looking for dynamic sql, you can use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And don't confuse "characters" with "bytes" - a common problem. Not certain how you connect "script" to "variable" - so this might be a tool or usage issue. Perhaps this is an issue with dynamic sql?

Comment: your understanding that variables can only contain 8000 characters is wrong, making the rest of this question redundant, `nvarchar(max)` etc can contain 2GB of content, i.e a billion double byte characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had many cases like this and the simpliest and free tool to be used is Notepad++. Just copy your script there and start selecting characters (you can first Ctrl+A to see whether the script is more than 8000 characters at all). There is "Sel" parameter in the status bar in the borrom, when it reaches about 8000 cheracters - just break your current variable and start a new one.
[image]